How to simplify the following regular expression?
I need to match 20 numbers in a string as follows，and then do a text replacement:
    0.61    -0.60    0.06    0.46    1.07      0.    0.47    0.07    0.61    -176.
    1.53    1.15    -176    176    NA    .05    0.05    2.65    176.    1.32

In this string, numbers may exist in several formats as follows:

Positive and negative integers without decimal point, e.g. 176, -176;
Positive and negative integers with a decimal point, e.g. 176., -176.;
Positive and negative real numbers with integer parts, e.g. 1.76, -1.76, 0.76, -0.76;
Positive and negative real numbers without integer parts, e.g. .76, -.076;
Partially missing numbers: NA;

After text replacement, the string mentioned above should like:
0.61,-0.60,0.06,0.46,1.07,0.,0.47,0.07,0.61,-176.,1.53,1.15,-176,176,NA,.05,0.05,2.65,176.,1.32

The content in my file is shown below, I only want to match two of the rows of data and nothing else.
H IIX092821 
D brief description (Someone et al., 1992)
R PMID:71516566
A Author(s)
T Title of the article
J Journal reference
C ARGP820102    0.961  MIYS850101    0.822  NAKH900106    0.810
  EISD860103    0.810  KYTJ820101    0.806  JURD980101    0.800
  PUNT030101   -0.810  MIYS990102   -0.814  MIYS990101   -0.817
I    A/L     R/K     N/M     D/F     C/P     Q/S     E/T     G/W     H/Y     I/V
    0.61    -0.60    0.06    0.46    1.07      0.    0.47    0.07    0.61    -176.
    1.53    1.15    -176    176    NA    .05    0.05    2.65    176.    1.32
//
H IIX092821 
D brief description (Someone et al., 1992)
R PMID:71516566
A Author(s)
T Title of the article
J Journal reference
C ARGP820102    0.961  MIYS850101    0.822  NAKH900106    0.810
  EISD860103    0.810  KYTJ820101    0.806  JURD980101    0.800
  PUNT030101   -0.810  MIYS990102   -0.814  MIYS990101   -0.817
I    A/L     R/K     N/M     D/F     C/P     Q/S     E/T     G/W     H/Y     I/V
    0.61    -0.60    0.06    0.46    1.07      0.    0.47    0.07    0.61    -176.
    1.53    1.15    -176    176    NA    .05    0.05    2.65    176.    1.32
//
H IIX092821 
D brief description (Someone et al., 1992)
R PMID:71516566
A Author(s)
T Title of the article
J Journal reference
C VINM940102    0.874  VINM940103    0.837  RACS770101    0.837
  FUKS010103    0.834  MEIH800101    0.832  MIYS990104    0.822
  VINM940101    0.821  PARS000101    0.816  GUYH850102    0.811
  CIDH920104   -0.801  BIOV880102   -0.804  RADA880108   -0.804
  ROSG850101   -0.807  MIYS850101   -0.811  MEEJ810101   -0.818
  BASU050102   -0.819  BIOV880101   -0.825  NISK860101   -0.828
  ZHOH040101   -0.833  WERD780101   -0.842  ZHOH040103   -0.846
  CIDH920101   -0.864  CIDH920105   -0.866  CIDH920102   -0.873
I    A/L     R/K     N/M     D/F     C/P     Q/S     E/T     G/W     H/Y     I/V
1.041    1.038   1.117   1.033   0.960   1.165   1.094   1.142   0.982   1.002
0.967    1.093   0.947   0.930   1.055   1.169   1.073   0.925   0.961   0.982
//

I use the regular expression as follows:
^\s+(NA|-?\d*\.?\d*)\s+(NA|-?\d*\.?\d*)\s+(NA|-?\d*\.?\d*)\s+(NA|-?\d*\.?\d*)\s+(NA|-?\d*\.?\d*)\s+(NA|-?\d*\.?\d*)\s+(NA|-?\d*\.?\d*)\s+(NA|-?\d*\.?\d*)\s+(NA|-?\d*\.?\d*)\s+(NA|-?\d*\.?\d*)\r\s+(NA|-?\d*\.?\d*)\s+(NA|-?\d*\.?\d*)\s+(NA|-?\d*\.?\d*)\s+(NA|-?\d*\.?\d*)\s+(NA|-?\d*\.?\d*)\s+(NA|-?\d*\.?\d*)\s+(NA|-?\d*\.?\d*)\s+(NA|-?\d*\.?\d*)\s+(NA|-?\d*\.?\d*)\s+(NA|-?\d*\.?\d*)$

To make it easier to read, I've broken up the regular expression mentioned above as follows：
^                   # line begin
\s+(NA|-?\d*\.?\d*) # number 1
\s+(NA|-?\d*\.?\d*)
\s+(NA|-?\d*\.?\d*)
\s+(NA|-?\d*\.?\d*)
\s+(NA|-?\d*\.?\d*)
\s+(NA|-?\d*\.?\d*)
\s+(NA|-?\d*\.?\d*)
\s+(NA|-?\d*\.?\d*)
\s+(NA|-?\d*\.?\d*)
\s+(NA|-?\d*\.?\d*) # number 10
\r                  # enter
\s+(NA|-?\d*\.?\d*) # number 11
\s+(NA|-?\d*\.?\d*)
\s+(NA|-?\d*\.?\d*)
\s+(NA|-?\d*\.?\d*)
\s+(NA|-?\d*\.?\d*)
\s+(NA|-?\d*\.?\d*)
\s+(NA|-?\d*\.?\d*)
\s+(NA|-?\d*\.?\d*)
\s+(NA|-?\d*\.?\d*)
\s+(NA|-?\d*\.?\d*) # number 20
$                   # line end

Then I use the following statement for text replacement:
$1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$9,$10,$11,$12,$13,$14,$15,$16,$17,$18,$19,$20

I did the whole thing with the replace function in notepad++.
My question is, how do I simplify the regular expression I mentioned above for matching numbers, while ensuring that I can do the text replacement correctly?

Are you using any programming language?  Your current regex is about as clean as you can get, assuming you want to replace with separate capture groups.

If you are using a specific language, then you can just ensure that you find 20 matches of (NA|-?\d*\.?\d*)

@Tim Biegeleisen Since there is not a lot of data to process at the moment, I am using the text replacement function in notepad++ that supports regular expressions.

@OneCricketeer No, that approach won't work in NPP, because only the last captured group would be available in $1 to use as a replacement.

@OneCricketeer Thanks for your reply, I'm not using any programming language, I'm just curious if this regular expression can be simplified in some way.

what else is in the file that should not be changed?

@jhnc Thanks for your reply, I've added what can't be changed in the file.

In your added example you have commas after the first numbers. Is that really so? You have some numbers separated by commas, and others not?

Why do you need to match the numbers/entries? Can't you just replace the white spaces with commas?

the current regex matches "numbers" like . and -.

@RoToRa I need to structure this unstructured data and then store it (in a specific order) into a database. Since there is some other information in the file that is also in a number format similar to the one I mentioned above, I can only prevent extracting other irrelevant information by matching 20 numbers at once. I noticed a lot of duplicates in the regular expression I wrote, and I thought there might be some way to optimize it that I'm not aware of.

My purpose in replacing the separators for these numbers with commas is so that the data can be more easily segmented in subsequent processing. In fact, I also add specific identifiers to mark the rows I need to extract during the replacement process so that I can easily extract the data I need with another regular expression. But I don't think these are very relevant to my problem. I naively thought I could simplify my regular expression by quantifiers or whatever, which seems unlikely at this point. Thank you very much for your replies.

@jhnc Yes, you're right, my regular expression isn't exactly right and it's ugly, but it works.

can a line of 10 "numbers" appear that is not immediately followed by another such line?

@jhnc No, the information I need to extract is all 2 lines of numbers and each line is fixed to be 10 numbers.

In your added example you have commas after the first numbers. Is that really so? You have some numbers separated by commas, and others not?

If the input string has long stretches of white space, then the OP's regex suffers from exponential backtracking.

@trincotThere were some errors in the example I gave and I have fixed it. All the numbers are separated by spaces.

Try:
\s+(-?(?:\d+(?:\.\d*)?|\.\d+|NA))

and replace with
$1,

See: regex101
NOTE that you will have a trailing , that you can then remove with ,$; replace by an empty string.

Explanation

\s+: match any preceeding spaces (to remove them)
(...): capter the numbers to group 1

-?: Numbers may begin with leading 0
(?:...): then they can either be:

\d+: a number of interger digits
(?:...)?: followed optionally by

\.: a dot which might
\d*: be followed by any amount of digits


|: or
\.\d+: (no leading int) a dot followed by digits
|: or
NA: literal "NA"






Sorry, as I wasn't clear before, there is some other content in my file that can't be modified (I've added this part to my question), and these include numbers as well. Therefore, the solution you gave is not feasible as it would match irrelevant content.

can you try: (?<!\w{4}\d{6})\s{4}(-?(?:\d+(?:\.\d*)?|\.\d+|NA))? The negative lookahead asserts that the identifiers in "C" of pattern \w{4}\d{6} cannot be preceeding

I have tested the regular expression you provided and in half the cases it is fine. But in some cases it fails. I have added the part that the regular expression you have given cannot handle to my question. Thank you very much for your reply, I think there may not be any good solution for this problem.

@MasterLu try (?<!\w{4}\d{6}\s|\w{4}\d{6})\s{3,4}(-?(?:\d+(?:.\d*)?|.\d+|NA))

Thank you very much for your reply, but it still has some problems within this example. I don't think there may be any better way to improve this ugly regular expression of mine.

@MasterLu see update on same link; NA changed to NA\b, ensuring to not grab "NA" as part of a string

it still has some problems within this example.

Thank you very much for your reply, your regular expressions seem to be getting more and more correct, but just like the ones I've written they are also getting more and more complex, and have gradually defeated the original purpose of my question, which was to simplify a complex regular expression.

@MasterLu I see your point. But as long as the restrictions are not redundant you need to handle each one which in turn elongates the expression.. Please still consider upvoting trincots and my answer if they solve the problem, so other people might be helped in the future

I would suggest this regex replace in Notepad++, using a look-ahead assertion (?=   ):
Find what: [ ]*(-?\.?\b\d[\d.]*|\bNA)\s+(?=-?[\d.]|NA\b)
Replace with: $1,
Search mode:
⦿ Regular expression
Replace All
With a bit stronger requirement in the look-ahead, it could be:
[ ]*(-?\.?\b\d[\d.]*|\bNA)\s+(?=(?:-?[\d.]+|NA)[\s,])

Thank you very much for your reply. In most cases your regular expression is correct, but your regular expression matches the period in the following unrelated message. This sentence is: J Eur. J. Biochem. 128, 565-575 (1982).

Alright. I updated to not match such a period.

Any other cases to deal with?

With your restriction that a valid line of 10 "numbers" is always followed by a valid second line, a sed solution can be:
sed -E '
    # skip unless pattern space contains valid first line
    /^([[:space:]]+(NA|-?[0-9]*?([0-9]\.|\.?[0-9])[0-9]*)){10}$/ !b

    # append second line to pattern space
    N

    # trim leading whitespace
    # (the regex does not match lines with trailing whitespace)
    s/^[[:space:]]+//

    # convert whitespace sequence to comma
    s/[[:space:]]+/,/g

    # implicit print
' infile >outfile

An awk solution that does more checking is:
awk -v OFS=, '
    {
        if ( !/^([[:space:]]+(NA|-?[0-9]*?([0-9]\.|\.?[0-9])[0-9]*)){10}$/ ) {
            # not a valid line - print and reset state 
            print p $0
            p = ""
        }
        else if (p) {
            # this is second line

            # prepend saved first line
            $0 = p $0

            # assignment causes re-split and trim
            $1 = $1

            # print, and reset state
            print
            p = ""
        }
        else {
            # save first line
            p = $0 RS
        }
    }
' infile >outfile

The regex in the question has the virtue of legibility. The one here is shorter but not necessarily simpler. It can be less repetitive because it is just used to locate lines, not to change them.

Running on your sample input gives:
H IIX092821 
D brief description (Someone et al., 1992)
R PMID:71516566
A Author(s)
T Title of the article
J Journal reference
C ARGP820102    0.961  MIYS850101    0.822  NAKH900106    0.810
  EISD860103    0.810  KYTJ820101    0.806  JURD980101    0.800
  PUNT030101   -0.810  MIYS990102   -0.814  MIYS990101   -0.817
I    A/L     R/K     N/M     D/F     C/P     Q/S     E/T     G/W     H/Y     I/V
0.61,-0.60,0.06,0.46,1.07,0.,0.47,0.07,0.61,-176.,1.53,1.15,-176,176,NA,.05,0.05,2.65,176.,1.32
//
H IIX092821 
D brief description (Someone et al., 1992)
R PMID:71516566
A Author(s)
T Title of the article
J Journal reference
C ARGP820102    0.961  MIYS850101    0.822  NAKH900106    0.810
  EISD860103    0.810  KYTJ820101    0.806  JURD980101    0.800
  PUNT030101   -0.810  MIYS990102   -0.814  MIYS990101   -0.817
I    A/L     R/K     N/M     D/F     C/P     Q/S     E/T     G/W     H/Y     I/V
0.61,-0.60,0.06,0.46,1.07,0.,0.47,0.07,0.61,-176.,1.53,1.15,-176,176,NA,.05,0.05,2.65,176.,1.32
//
H IIX092821 
D brief description (Someone et al., 1992)
R PMID:71516566
A Author(s)
T Title of the article
J Journal reference
C VINM940102    0.874  VINM940103    0.837  RACS770101    0.837
  FUKS010103    0.834  MEIH800101    0.832  MIYS990104    0.822
  VINM940101    0.821  PARS000101    0.816  GUYH850102    0.811
  CIDH920104   -0.801  BIOV880102   -0.804  RADA880108   -0.804
  ROSG850101   -0.807  MIYS850101   -0.811  MEEJ810101   -0.818
  BASU050102   -0.819  BIOV880101   -0.825  NISK860101   -0.828
  ZHOH040101   -0.833  WERD780101   -0.842  ZHOH040103   -0.846
  CIDH920101   -0.864  CIDH920105   -0.866  CIDH920102   -0.873
I    A/L     R/K     N/M     D/F     C/P     Q/S     E/T     G/W     H/Y     I/V
1.041,   1.038   1.117   1.033   0.960   1.165   1.094   1.142   0.982   1.002
0.967,   1.093   0.947   0.930   1.055   1.169   1.073   0.925   0.961   0.982
//


I think *? is fairly new (https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9799919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_04_06); if not available, just * would work here

Thank you very much for your reply, but your method seems to be more complicated than my regular expression, which has taken away from the original purpose of my question. I hope your reply can be of help to someone who needs it.

no worries. yes, it is more complicated, though potentially more generally applicable. your original regex is legible/maintainable, so if it works (note trincot's comment re catastrophic backtracking) then it's not a bad approach. however, if your problem was modified to be, say,  the same reformatting but also to add 3 to each number, then regex-only (or sed) solutions would be rather hard; the awk solution would just need one extra line. the basic idea is to divide and conquer - split the code into a part that finds candidates, and a part that operates on those candidates
